# How to read additional JSON attribute(s) which is not mapped to a @RequestBody model object in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a RestController which looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestBody User user) {

    System.out.println(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}
```

And the User model which looks like this

```
class User {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String state;

}
```

I have a requirement wherein users can pass some extra additional attribute(s) in the input JSON, something like this

```
{
"name": "abc",
"city": "xyz",
"state": "pqr",
"zip":"765234",
"country": "india"
}
```

'zip' and 'country' are the additional attributes in the input JSON.

Is there any way in Spring Boot we can get these additional attributes in the Request Body ?

I know a way wherein I can use either a "Map" or "JsonNode" or "HttpEntity" as Requestbody parameter. But I don't want to use these classes as I would loose the javax.validation that can be used inside "User" model object.

Comment: you can change the User class and add this attributes

Comment: Add a `Map` to the user object to contain everything else. Create a setter containing a key and value and annotate with `@JsonAnySetter`.

Comment: These additional attributes (name and number )are not known to the API

Comment: @M.Deinum  We don't want any attribute in the input which points to a JSON. User have no idea about the mandatory attributes and extra attributes

Comment: Have you actually READ the comment and answer. You can post whatever with that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend your `User` DTO with a `Map<String, String>` and create a setter which is annotated with `@JsonAnySetter`. For all unknown properties this method will be called.

```
class User {

    private final Map<String, Object> details= new HashMap<>);

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addDetail(String key, Object value) {
      this.details.add(key, value);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getDetails() { return this.details; }
}
```

Now you can obtain everything else through the `getDetails()`.

Comment: I want validation on the elements of the map. I can use javax.validation like      
private final Map<@NotBlank String, @NotNull Object> details= new HashMap<>);      But these attribute name and type of value would not be known to me. I will have a metadata where I can have the Type information and what kind of validation I can put on a particular attribute name. How to validate then?

Comment: You would probably need to write a custom constraint validator for that as that is quite a specific usecase you have there.